# Bing News Search Always returning response in English

Tags: azure, bing

I am trying to fetch news filter with some language and category. for this i am trying to use API parameters specified by team.

I am using Bing News API Version 7.0 and referring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-news-api-v7-reference#market-codes.

I tried setting the following method:

a) AcceptLanguage =  hi in Headers and using url: https://sathi-api-cognitive-search-news.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0/news?cc=IN&category=sports&textFormat=HTML&count=50&sortBy=Date&textDecorations=true

b) USING setLang as hi or hi-IN https://sathi-api-cognitive-search-news.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0/news?setLang=hi-IN&mkt=en-IN&category=sports&textFormat=HTML&count=50&sortBy=Date&textDecorations=true. also i tried mkt as en-IN or hi-IN.

It always return response in format of

```
"name": "With Hundred postponed, Colin Graves decides to step down as ECB chairman on Aug 31",
        "url": "https://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket/with-hundred-postponed-colin-graves-decides-to-step-down-as-ecb-chairman-on-aug-31/story-OCvUauUaF768d3hkbwlnEI.html",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.B7533C254FFE2947A1E32EFABC8794FC&pid=News",
                "width": 700,
                "height": 393
            }
        },
        "description": "Graves, who was appointed as chairman in May 2015, will be replaced by Ian Watmore after being ratified in the AGM at the end of the month. Graves is expected to take over as ICC’s next chairman, replacing Shashank Manohar.",
        "about": [
            {
                "readLink": "https://sathi-api-cognitive-search-news.cognitiveservices.azure.com/api/v7/entities/4dcc40e4-d6dd-cad2-9200-dbc9d57f8972",
                "name": "Colin Graves"
            }
```

I tried some other combination as well.

While trying these methods, i feel documentation is a bit confusing and parameters are mixed up. like headers and GET-parameters. i am not expecting this from microsoft where user experience is always their top priority.

I want to know what combination to apply for getting news in regional language.

- One more issue I faced is SortBy parameter. I was trying to verify it with published news date and it seems the news is not sorted at all.

Comment: which language you're trying to use?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Hindi, hi-IN

Comment: hindi is not a supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/language-support

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio But hindi is listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-news-api-v7-reference#bing-supported-languages

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Also i would like to understand difference between mkt and setLang. it seems language parameter already there in mkt. Then what is the use of setLang?

Comment: the page you're using is from 2017. I believe it's outdated

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I thought its version control so if i am using v7.0 and page state v7.0 then parameter specified should work right. also there is no clear understanding in page that it will not work. Azure user dashboard refer me to page while using APIs.